# Add a message to p:messages using JavaScript

Tags: primefaces

I have a messages element on my page like this:

```
<p:messages id="messages" widgetVar="myMessages" showDetail="false" closable="true">
     <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:messages>
```

I'd like to add a message using JavaScript. [Looking at the docs](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.Messages.html),I should be able to  do something like this:

```
PF('myMessages').appendMessage({detail:'Upload your files before saving',severity:'error'});
```

Or maybe like this:

```
PF('myMessages').add({detail:'Upload your files before saving',severity:'error'});
```

But I get a error that says "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendMessage')*"

Comment: `appendMessage` is working for me. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml , F12, `PF('widget_j_idt344_messages').appendMessage({detail:'Upload your files before saving',severity:'error'});`

Comment: where are you getting widget_j_idt344_messages? Even with widgetVar="myMessages", I don't see "myMessages" anywhere in the page source? How do you have your messages configured that they have a widget ID?

Comment: I just used the showcase. It's working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the primefaces 10 community download.

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7798

Comment: That's why you should always add a [mcve]. The showcase is running on 12.